# Как заменить символ в строке на языке Си?

Tags: c

при изучении языка Си возник вопрос, почему не получается изменить первую букву строк name?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char name[] = "QWE";
    name[0] = "R";
    printf("%s", name);
    return 0;
}
```

При сборке вылезает *warning: assignment to 'char' from 'char *' makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]*. Запуск программы выводит вместо ожидаемого "RWE", "DWE".

Comment: `name[0] = 'R';` ?

Answer (score 1):

В языке С двойные кавычки `"` обозначают строку, массив с завершаешим нуливым символом `\0` а одинарные кавычки `'` одиночный символ, если вы хотите на определном месте строки переписат символ нужно указать что вы переписываете символ.

```
name[0] = 'R';
```

а не пытаетесь на место символа записать строку.

Answer (score 1):

В си по-разному записываются символы и строки (символы в одинарных кавычках, строки - в двойных).
При этом строка - это просто массив символов.
Поэтому `"R"` имеет тип const char* (т.е. константный указатель на массив символов)

В строке `name[0] = "R";` Вы пытаетесь присвоить символу строку (т.е. указатель), из-за чего компилятор производит неявное преобразование (о чем, собственно, Вас и предупреждает)

Исправьте двойные кавычки вокруг R на одинарные.